# What is the process of bringing equal elements together in an array?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have a large array of mostly random numbers, with a few elements equal to each other. I need to change the array so that any elements that are equal are next to each other. Of course, sorting solves this problem but since I do not require the entire array to be in order I am assuming there are faster algorithms for this.

I am mainly asking what is this process called so I can read up on it further. I need to understand the different approaches that exist and so am not looking for a specific algorithm, but any suggestions for such would be appreciated as well.

Many thanks.

Comment: I assume the values of these numbers are bounded? If there are $m$ distinct values in the array then any algorithm which identifies equal elements would be $\Omega(m)$.

Comment: There's another question with the same content here:  http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19170/the-theoretical-upper-bounds-for-duplicate-detection-in-a-set-of-objects .  I'll flag this as a duplicate, but I think that will answer your question.